# How To Show Which Process Owns Disk Space In Linux

Tags: linux, file, handle, space, disk

I have run these commands to determine disk space usage on my Linux system.

`Filesystem Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on /dev/mapper/foovg-foo 326G  202G  108G  66% /export/data/foo`

`du -sk * | awk '{sum += $1}END{print sum}'`
132161064  ~ 126GB

So, 202G - 126G = 76G difference.

Where is the 76G disk space?
How can I find out which process holding the file handle?
What is the file name deleted?

In Linux,  the file descriptors under `/proc/pid/fd/` are soft link to the actual file.

Comment: "du -k |sort -n" should give you a hint about where to go looking for it.

Comment: You might like Unix&Linux stackexchange http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not it's the cause, you can see which processes are holding onto deleted files using `lsof`. Something like this might help:

```
lsof | grep '(deleted)$' | sort -rnk 7
```

In other words, grab all deleted files and sort them in descending order by size.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a `*` wildcard in your du command so it won't pick up (hidden) directories which begin with `.`. For example, there could be `.nfs` files taking up space, which your command will not pick up.

You can also use the `-c` option to tell `du` to produce the total, instead of using `awk`.

Use the following command instead:

```
# cd /export/data/foo
# du -ch .
```

This command will also give you the sizes of all sub-directories so you can find which one is using more space.